# Using Adafruit Trinket M0 (SAMD21) as a USB to Serial converter

Tags: usb, serial, ftdi, samd21

I wanted to know if it is possible to use SAMD21 as a USB to Serial converter like the usual FTDI chips ? If yes could you please point how to achieve that. I believe that Adafruit Trinket was used somewhere like this but i can't seem to find it.

The idea is that i already have the trinket, what i don't have is a FTDI device and i need to program a micro-controller that can be programmed via USB to Serial converters.

Comment: Beyond an affirmative answer to "is it possible" this question is too broad for the mission of this site.  You're really looking for a tutorial or code, and it's not the role of this site to provide that.

Answer (score 1):

The USB CDC (which provides a COM port in Windows) is usually one of the USB examples provided by the MCU vendor. In this case Appnote [AN_42337](http://www.microchip.com//wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en591628).

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but its kind of difficult going through the whole document. Is it possible to have a summary? I also find it difficult to comprehend the answer.

Comment: Turbo J has given you the answer, that document is the summary. USB is quite complicated and fast modern microcontrollers are quite complicated, you need to be willing to read their resources.